# Broken terminal - [forkpty: Resource temporarily unavailable][Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]

Tags: terminal, macos-sierra

I can't start up my terminal on MacOS 10.12

I get the following message:

```
[forkpty: Resource temporarily unavailable][Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I simply restarted my computer to resolve the issue. Hope this helps anyone else in the future.

Comment: Same here but it happens on daily basis.

Comment: See my solution above. Restarting your computer every single time is hardly a fix.

Answer (score 11):

This explination gives slightly more insight into what id goin on.  It seems you have too many processes running on your computer and there are certain limits in place.

http://blog.ghostinthemachines.com/2010/01/19/mac-os-x-fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable/

Comment: This happened when I had Android Studio open. When I closed it, everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo sysctl kern.tty.ptmx_max=255` (or 511, or whatever) should fix it.

My default (in El Capitan) was 127. (As a tmux user, I need
more than that.)

To learn more:

```
sysctl | grep max
ulimit -a
launchctl limit

cat /private/etc/launchd.conf
cat /private/etc/sysctl.conf

man 8 sysctl
```

Comment: This might be a silly question but if terminal won't start up, how are you supposed to enter these commands?

Comment: Restart your computer, ha ha. Or restart in safe mode if it's coming up right away :)

Comment: You can open up activity monitor -> Memory -> kill process thats eating up memory -> Then type command

Comment: 511 didn't work for me, but I set it to 999 and was able to open a new terminal window.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you opened too many apps, so computer's Memory not enough.
I just opened too many apps, and my iterm2 & terminal broke down, till quitted some useless app, reopen the two, everything going to be OK.
My Mac is MBA2017 8G.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for almost a week and it was driving me nuts because I would have to restart my computer every. single. time.

Sorry but restarting your computer every single time is hardly a solution.

In my case, it was a cron process. I had the process running every minute which seemed to be using up a lot of memory. Steps to solve the problem in my case were:

1. Run crontab -e and reduced the frequency of the cron process running.
2. Run `Activity Monitor.`
3. If the `Activity Monitor` icon jumps up and down and doesn't open up, close down some programs. In my case, I shut down Evernote and Slack. That freed up some memory, I think and Activity Monitor opened up.
4. Click on the `Process Name` tab in `Activity Monitor` to arrange processes in alphabetical order.
5. Scroll down, and you may see a process that keeps repeating. (Here, I saw a lot of `cron`)
6. You want to stop all those processes. Select all the renegade processes and in the top left corner, click the `x` to quit them all. .
7. That solved my problem.

I will watch over the next few days. If anything changes, I will update. Otherwise, that means it worked.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 2):

In my case the culprit was `visual studio code` closing it works
`chrome` too takes too much memory sometime

During that time chrome tab doesn't open, apps fails to start etc

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.tty.ptmx_max=768
```

default is 511